# How to repeat commands from history in ksh vi-mode

Tags: shell, ksh

Say I have a hundred commands in my shell's history, and now I'd like to repeat commands 74 through 78. In the emacs mode of bash/ksh/zsh, I would navigate back to command 74 then hit Control-O on each command to execute it and continue with the next. In vi mode I can navigate back to command 74 readily enough, but how do I then execute it and see command 75?

Answer (score 1):

Press `<esc>`, then 'k' until you get to the one you want, or something like '7k' if you know how many back, then enter to execute.

Comment: I will learn to count how many times I type 'k' getting back to (in my example) command 74, then type '16k' to get to command 75 and again for command 76 &c. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
set -o emacs
```

You may be in vi mode. You can add the line above to your `~/.profile` file.

Or you can add the following to your `~/.kshrc` file:

```
: ${EDITOR:=emacs}
```